# Passing array of int to Api Controller using $http in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Could I get some help with this issue please:

I'm trying to send an array of int from my javascript function to my api controller but can't get the correct configuration for the controller - the projectsId passed into the controller is always null.

Javascript function:

```
    getProducts: function (projects) {            
        return $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/api/settings/products',
            data: projects
        }).then(function (result) {
            return result.data;
        }, function (result) {
            return result;
        });
```

The projects being passed ito getProducts is an int array.

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("products")]
    public IHttpActionResult Export([FromBody] int[] projectIds)
    {
        var exportProducts = new List<Product>();
```

Thank you.

This is the result of console.log(projects):
[image: This is the result of console.log(projectIds)]

Answer (score 1):

where you'e calling `getProducts` the input parameter should look something like:

```
var products = [1, 2, 3];
```

To assist with debugging, add a `console.log(projects)` to your `getProducts` function.

Comment: Thanks for your reply David - I've added the console.log(projects) ..

Comment: Thanks David! The problem is with the array I was passing in. It is not equalivent to var products = [1,2,3]. When populated this as a test it worked. Man alive! thanks very much!